# CSS: Hyphenation syllable if not possible break word

Tags: html, css

I want to break my text.
Actualy I use 
`word-break: break-all;`
This does not look good so.

I want to try to cut after space and only if there's no possibility, cut it after any letter.

```
<div class="name td" style="word-break: all;">
TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTe stTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
</div>

display: table-cell;
border: thin solid black;
padding: 5px;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
word-break: break-all;
```

I want to break after space if possible, else after any letter. Any ideas?

Comment: "word-break: normal;" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `word-wrap: break-word;` will solve this for you, but not with the existing markup in combination with `display: table-cell`, as `table-cell` grows with content.

So to make your case work, you need to set `table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;` on the `table`, and add a `div` wrapper, which has the `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.td .wrapword {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="name td">
    <div class="wrapword">
      TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTe stTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

If growing horizontally is fine, then `word-wrap: break-word;` is enough.

```css
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="name td">
      TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTe stTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @stefen Updated my answer with a second sample...if you it is okay that the table cell grows horizontally

Comment: This means growing if its not possible to break after space or somesthing.
Not right for me but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try **word-wrap:break-word**, it will break when it reaches to end of outer wrapper width.

```
<div class="name td" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
</div>
```